# Preferred way of using asynchronous function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I know two ways to use asynchronous functions in useEffect. I read somewhere that the first way is wrong. Which way do you think is better?

first method

```
async function fetchData() {
  const result = await axios(
    'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react',
  );
  setData(result.data);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [miliko]);
```

second method

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [miliko]);
```

Comment: reference to your question [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326)

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are correct and will work as long as the data that fetchData uses is within its lexical scope

The only difference in the two approaches is that a new reference for `fetchData` will be created on every render in the first case, whereas in the second case a new reference will be create only on initial render and when `miliko` changes

To keep the relevant code together, you can go ahead with the second approach which will it easier for you to cancel the previous request if a new request is made so that you don't see inconsistencies

```
useEffect(() => {

    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react', {
             cancelToken: source.token
         }
      );
      setData(result.data);
    }

  fetchData();

  return () => {
      source.cancel('Effect cleared');
  }
}, [miliko]);
```